# Get only (mydomain.com) rather than (mydomain.com/home.aspx)

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a built a website in asp.net WebForms. What I want to achieve is to get www.mydomain.com instead of www.mydomain.com/home.aspx. Home.aspx is my landing page. I want the user to only see www.mydomain.com in the address bar and show him home.aspx. How can it be accomplished with Url-rewriting?

Comment: If it's just for your landing page then you don't need url-rewrite, just set home.aspx in your default pages in IIS

Answer (score 0):

Rename a first page ( Home.aspx) to index.aspx or default.aspx and set this page to default page in VisualStudio (R-Click->Set Default page) on index.aspx  .